# How do I turn a sequence of sequences into a map, where the values are the count of the first item in the sequence?

Tags: clojure

I have data like `(("generic" 7) ("ore" 1) ("generic" 4) ("wood" 6) ("wheat" 3) ("generic" 2) ("generic" 9) ("sheep" 5) ("brick" 8))`

and I want to turn it into

```
 {"brick"   1
  "generic" 4
  "sheep"   1
  "ore"     1
  "wheat"   1
  "wood"    1}
```

Since "generic" appears 4 times in the data, I want the key to be "generic" and the value to be 4. Since "sheep" appears 1 time in the data, I want the key to be "sheep" and the value to be "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map), [`first`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/first) and [`frequencies`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/frequencies):

```
(->> '(("generic" 7) ("ore" 1) ("generic" 4) ("wood" 6) ("wheat" 3) ("generic" 2) ("generic" 9) ("sheep" 5) ("brick" 8))
     (map first)
     frequencies)

=> {"generic" 4, "ore" 1, "wood" 1, "wheat" 1, "sheep" 1, "brick" 1}
```

([`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) is "thread-last" macro.)

Comment: Should `frequencies` be wrapped in `()`?

Comment: Both variants will work, but the one without `()` is better.

Comment: Why is the one without `()` better?

Comment: See [Clojure Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#threading-macros-and-optional-parentheses)